# How to create a paint app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, graphics

I would like to develop a MS paint like app for the iPhone. Could you guys point me to some sample or tutorials on this topic? I'm new to Objective C and Xcode. Thanks

Comment: Break down your project and focus in your question if want any answers

Comment: I'm really new to iPhone development. Just need something to get me started

Comment: I was going to vote to close because this is so open ended, but really it's not on second thought..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try playing with this sample project.  It's a very simple paint app using Open GL.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328

Answer (score 3):

No need for Open GL indeed. You can check out this [blog post](http://caplesscoder.blogspot.com/2012/08/capless-paint-for-iphone.html) . It has a great example code for a simple paint app in iPhone.